# ¿Cómo desloguerase de conexión ssh con paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh

Busqué en internet pero solo encuentro cómo loguearme, no como desloguearme, el código sería algo como:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('192.168.1.4',22,'alguien', 'contraseña')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("echo hello")
```

pero necesitaría desloguearme una vez ejecutado el comando.
Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la documentación, puedes usar el método [`close()`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.close), en tu caso sería así:

```
ssh.close()
```

Hay una nota importante en la documentación:

> Failure to do this may, in some situations, cause your Python
> interpreter to hang at shutdown (often due to race conditions). It’s
> good practice to close your client objects anytime you’re done using
> them, instead of relying on garbage collection.

El consejo, como buena práctica, es cerrar la conexión ni bien dejamos de usarla.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte, dejo la documentación: http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/